# Is it possible to have the setEmptyView of a listView (from a ListFragment) to be se as a imageView and a textView?

Tags: java, xml, listview

I know it's possible to have a textView set as a emptyView, but is it possible to have a imageView and a textView.

I added the imageView and the TextView in a linearLayout and gave the Layout the ID = empty.

Injected the View in the list fragment and got the code below

Java

@InjectView(R.id.empty)
    View empty;

```
 View empty = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.empty, null);
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setEmptyView(empty);
```

and XML

```
    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/empty"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/message_blank"/>

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/gap_huge"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/gap_huge"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/gap_large"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:tag="akkurat"
                        android:text="text"
                        android:textColor="#A0A0A0"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_small"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

running this code I get this error

```
enter code here05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.xxxx.xx/uk.co.xxxx.messaging.MessagingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at uk.co.x.messaging.MessagingPortraitFragment.onCreateView(MessagingPortraitFragment.java:99)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5382)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
05-08 16:26:21.673: E/AndroidRuntime(2327):     ... 11 more

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error as you until I moved the code to the Fragment's onStart() method:

```
View empty = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.empty, null);
getActivity().addContentView(empty, getListView().getLayoutParams());
getListView().setEmptyView(empty);
```